# Battleship in C, arrays and structs

Tags: c, arrays, struct

So i'm trying to build a simple replica of a battleship game in C, i create a struct `Navio` to represent the ships.

```
struct Navio{
    int *cords;
    int tam;
    int hits;
    int afundado;
};
```

the cords variable is an array with size of tam * 2, that have the cordinates of my ship. like this:`[0,0,1,1,1,2]` i have a ship of size 3 and  cords of size 6.

The player has to place each cords on it's own. but when i'm trying to put more than 1 ship i get an `segmentation fault`. The code that i have to place each cord is that: (the code works 100% with one ship, i suspect that the problem is when i declare the `cords` array inside the `placeBoats` function, but i don't know how to make).

```
    void placeBoats(int board[nLin][nCol],struct Navio *navios, int nNavios){
    int navio, tamanho, i, l, lin, col, navAnterior;
    system("clear");

    for(navio = 0; navio < nNavios; navio++){ //Para cada navio
        //pega tamanho de cada navio
        while(1){
            printf("\nTamanho do Navio %d: ", navio+1);
            scanf("%d", &tamanho);
            if(tamanho >= 2 && tamanho <= 6) break;
            else{
                printf("O tamanho do navio tem que ser no mínimo 2 casas e no máximo 6\n");
            }
        }

        navios[navio].tam = tamanho;
        int cords[tamanho * 2]; //array que armazena cordenadas de cada navio
        resetArray(cords, tamanho*2);

        //CORDENADAS DE CADA NAVIO
        printf("\nNAVIO %d", navio+1);
        for(i = 0, l = 0; i < tamanho * 2; i += 2, l++){
            //TO DO - VALDIAR POSIÇÃO
            while(1){
                printf("\nCordenadas %d\n", l + 1);
                printf("Linha Cordenada %d (0 - 5): ", l + 1);
                scanf("%d", &lin);
                //cords[i]
                printf("Coluna Cordenada %d (0 - 9): ", l + 1);
                scanf("%d", &col);
                //cords[i+1]
                if(validPlace(lin,col) && !checkColosion(lin,col, board)){
                    cords[i] = lin;
                    cords[i + 1] = col;
                    break;
                }
                else{
                    printf("Essa posição não é válida. Tente outra\n");
                }
            }

            board[lin][col] = 1;
            printBoard(board);
        }
        //bota array no struct
        copyArrayToStruct(cords, (tamanho * 2), navios, navio);
    }
}

void copyArrayToStruct(int *origem, int tamOrigem, struct Navio *navios, int index){
    int i;
    // printf("NAVIO %d: \n", index + 1);
    for(i = 0; i < tamOrigem; i+=2){
        navios[index].cords[i] = origem[i];
        navios[index].cords[i + 1] = origem[i + 1];
        // printf("X = %d - Y = %d\n", origem[i], origem[i+1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: tough to say, most of the places I see for potential segfaults are dependent on function arguments and user inputs, and we don't know what those are. One potential problem.. `cords[i + 1] = col;` will be out of bounds when/if `i >= (tamanho*2)-1`. Recommend running it in a debugger so you can see where it crashes. An [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be helpful.

Comment: insted of using a array to store all the cordinates i use a matrix and reset all values to -1, and interate over the ship size. so far it's working. but thanks man i'm new to C. doing a college project.

Answer (score 0):

GDB exists for a reason. And your problem is in the end of iteration. You think you are limiting the cycle to the end of the array, but you are probably limiting it further, as you change "cords[i+1]" , which is a bad practice.